# Are watermarks in pictures an obstacle to make deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

I want to train a CNN to see if the vehicle in the picture is damaged or not.

Will such watermarks, as in the picture, be an obstacle or cause problems when I train with these pictures a model.

I have not found such a topic unfortunately, I am sorry if it is placed wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer for that. CNN are very good at extracting fine pattern from image, Even they work well in texture understanding, where the difference between two classes is very minute. This depend on may factors such as datasets, training method, models, features-pattern etc. [Checkout this link for more info](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/bcnn/).